# Is there a way to see details of all the threads that a process has in Linux?

Tags: command-line, shell, process

For Windows, I think [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) shows you all the threads under a process.

Is there a similar command line utility for Linux that can show me details about all the threads a particular process is spawning?

---

I think I should have made myself more clear. **I do not want to see the process hierarcy, but a list of all the threads spawned by a particular process**

See this screenshot

[image]

**How can this be achieved in Linux?** Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268680/how-can-i-monitor-the-active-thread-count-of-a-process-jvm-on-linux

Answer (score 152, accepted):

The classical tool `top` shows processes by default but can be told to show threads with the `H` key press or `-H` command line option. There is also [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net), which is similar to `top` but has scrolling and colors; it shows all threads by default (but this can be turned off). `ps` also has a few options to show threads, especially `H` and `-L`.

There are also GUI tools that can show information about threads, for example [qps](http://qps.kldp.net/projects/qps) (a simple GUI wrapper around `ps`) or [conky](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conky/) (a system monitor with lots of configuration options).

For each process, a lot of information is available in `/proc/12345` where `12345` is the process ID. Information on each thread is available in `/proc/12345/task/67890` where `67890` is the kernel thread ID. This is where `ps`, `top` and other tools get their information.

Comment: My `htop` does not seem to show me the threads. They mention the `H` key as a way to swap between showing and hiding threads, but it works as the _Help_ key still...

Comment: @AlexisWilke Lowercase `h` for help, uppercase `H` to show/hide threads.

Answer (score 94):

### Listing threads under Linux

#### Current provide answers

I would like to make it clear that each answer here is providing you with exactly what you have specified, a list of all threads associated with a process, this may not be obvious in `htop` as it, by default, lists all threads on the system, not just the process but `top -H -p <pid>` works better for example:

```
top - 00:03:29 up 3 days, 14:49,  5 users,  load average: 0.76, 0.33, 0.18
Tasks:  18 total,   0 running,  18 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 22.6%us,  5.7%sy,  4.2%ni, 66.2%id,  0.8%wa,  0.5%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2063948k total,  1937744k used,   126204k free,   528256k buffers
Swap:  1052220k total,    11628k used,  1040592k free,   539684k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
30170 daniel    20   0  371m 140m 107m S 10.0  7.0   0:31.37 source:src
30066 daniel   -90   0  371m 140m 107m S  2.0  7.0   0:07.87 clementine
30046 daniel    20   0  371m 140m 107m S  0.0  7.0   0:32.05 clementine
30049 daniel    20   0  371m 140m 107m S  0.0  7.0   0:00.03 clementine
30050 daniel    20   0  371m 140m 107m S  0.0  7.0   0:00.31 clementine
30051 daniel    20   0  371m 140m 107m S  0.0  7.0   0:00.00 clementine
30052 daniel    20   0  371m 140m 107m S  0.0  7.0   0:00.00 clementine
30053 daniel    20   0  371m 140m 107m S  0.0  7.0   0:00.00 clementine
30054 daniel    20   0  371m 140m 107m S  0.0  7.0   0:00.03 clementine
30055 daniel    20   0  371m 140m 107m S  0.0  7.0   0:00.00 clementine
30056 daniel    20   0  371m 140m 107m S  0.0  7.0   0:00.00 clementine
30057 daniel    20   0  371m 140m 107m S  0.0  7.0   0:00.04 clementine
30058 daniel    20   0  371m 140m 107m S  0.0  7.0   0:00.00 clementine
30060 daniel    20   0  371m 140m 107m S  0.0  7.0   0:00.16 clementine
30061 daniel    20   0  371m 140m 107m S  0.0  7.0   0:00.00 clementine
30062 daniel    20   0  371m 140m 107m S  0.0  7.0   0:00.00 clementine
30064 daniel    20   0  371m 140m 107m S  0.0  7.0   0:00.00 clementine
30065 daniel    20   0  371m 140m 107m S  0.0  7.0   0:00.00 clementine
```

As a side note, the thread with `-90` is actually a real-time thread.

#### but

There's also another option which is true CLI: `ps`. It depends if you want to look for a process id (`pid`), for an `application name`, or more `filters`.

It does not work on MacOS or BSD, as there the `-T` parameter has a different meaning and there is no alternative to show threads.

##### `ps` with a `pid`

Use `ps -T -p <pid>`

- `-T` lists all threads
- `-p` specifies the process id

Here's an example:

```
$ ps -T -p 30046
  PID  SPID TTY          TIME CMD       # this is here for clarity
30046 30046 pts/2    00:00:17 clementine
30046 30049 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30050 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30051 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30052 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30053 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30054 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30055 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30056 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30057 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30058 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30060 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30061 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30062 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30064 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30065 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30066 pts/2    00:00:03 clementine
```

##### `ps` with an `application name`

Use `ps -T -C <application name>`

- `-T` lists all threads
- `-C` specifies the `<application name>`

Here's an example:

```
$ ps -e -T -C clementine
  PID  SPID TTY          TIME CMD       # this is here for clarity
30046 30046 pts/2    00:00:17 clementine
30046 30049 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30050 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30051 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30052 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30053 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30054 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30055 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30056 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30057 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30058 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30060 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30061 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30062 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30064 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30065 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30066 pts/2    00:00:03 clementine
```

##### `ps` with a `filter`

Use `ps -e -T | grep <filter>`

- `-e` shows all processes
- `-T` lists all threads
- `|` pipes the output to the next command
- `grep` this filters the contents by a `<filter>` (in this case `<application name>`)

Here's an example:

```
$ ps -e -T | grep clementine
  PID  SPID TTY          TIME CMD       # this is here for clarity
30046 30046 pts/2    00:00:17 clementine
30046 30049 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30050 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30051 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30052 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30053 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30054 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30055 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30056 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30057 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30058 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30060 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30061 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30062 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30064 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30065 pts/2    00:00:00 clementine
30046 30066 pts/2    00:00:03 clementine
```

Each of these has the same PID so you know they are in the same process.

Comment: thanks! What does SPID stand for?

Comment: Note that there's also ps -Tp <pid>, since the grep is a bit fuzzy unless you make it more complicated.

Comment: If you use `sed` instead of `grep` you can preserve the title with trivial code: `ps -e -T | sed -n '1p; /clementine/p;'`

Comment: thanx @Daniel ,, I am curious that .Can I use these PID's to    make a group as we do in multicast??

Comment: @Lazer it's hard to say what it stands for, but `man top` says it's an alias to `LWP` and `TID`, whereas LWP = lightweight process, and TID = thread identifier.

Comment: The SPID is confusingly the thread ID.

Comment: Hi Daniel, could you please edit your answer and add [Thomas Themel's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/892/is-there-a-way-to-see-details-of-all-the-threads-that-a-process-has-in-linux#comment4994_1056), that is, `ps -Tp <pid>`? It's quick, simple, and more reliable than grep (which could have false positives).

Comment: @Hi-Angel and Lazer - may be it stands for system process id?

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica will edit it shortly as virtual all Linux distros use procps-ng which has had the -p parameter for 20 years, and it also works on BSD systems including MacOS https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blame/48497fc40dfcc30fe35ca6be5c9add7f4d8e19e1/ps/ps.1#L64

Answer (score 43):

[htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/), a curses version of top, has a display option for showing all the threads for each process in a tree view. Starting `htop` and pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> will result in:

[image: Screenshot of htop]

Answer (score 30):

You may try to use:

```
/usr/bin/pstree $PID
```

For example:

```
# pstree -p `pidof iceweasel`
iceweasel(3630)─┬─{iceweasel}(3662)
                ├─{iceweasel}(3663)
                ├─{iceweasel}(3664)
                ├─{iceweasel}(3665)
                ├─{iceweasel}(3666)
                ├─{iceweasel}(3674)
                ├─{iceweasel}(3675)
                ├─{iceweasel}(3676)
                ├─{iceweasel}(3677)
                ├─{iceweasel}(3681)
                ├─{iceweasel}(3682)
                ...
```

Each thread has its own PID.  From the `man` page:

> Child threads of a process are found under the parent process and are shown with the process name in curly braces, e.g.
>
> ```
> icecast2---13*[{icecast2}]
> ```

Comment: each process has its own process id (pid).  pstree will not show you threads inside the processes

Answer (score 16):

The two standard tools to show process informations are `ps` and `top` (and `htop` which is similar/*improved*).

Notes:

- Many program change the apparent name of the threads to something meaningful, the tools below can either display the binary name or that apparent name (check PID 1086 in the examples below).
- In the examples below, I have removed most process to keep the answer short.
- The command arguments example below are common ones. check the manpage for alternate options (`ps -m`, `ps m`, `ps H`...)

**Realtime view of all or process, using `top -H`**

```
top - 16:24:42 up  3:49,  3 users,  load average: 0.23, 0.29, 0.31
Threads: 503 total,   2 running, 501 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  9.7 us,  1.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 88.5 id,  0.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   3938668 total,  2148708 used,  1789960 free,   133524 buffers
KiB Swap:  3903484 total,        0 used,  3903484 free.   822904 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 1054 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 rsyslogd
 1086 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 in:imuxsock
 1087 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 in:imklog
 1090 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.05 rs:main Q:Reg
 2452 fpiat     20   0   25292   7520   3580 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.69 bash         
 2495 fpiat     20   0   25088   6988   3256 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.05 bash
```

**Instant view of all process and threads, using `ps -eLf`**

```
$ ps -eLf
UID        PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      1054     1  1054  0    4 12:34 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
root      1054     1  1086  0    4 12:34 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
root      1054     1  1087  0    4 12:34 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
root      1054     1  1090  0    4 12:34 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
franklin  2452  2448  2452  0    1 12:35 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash
franklin  2495  2448  2495  0    1 12:36 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash
```

**Threads information of a process, using `ps -T`**

```
ps -T -C rsyslogd
  PID  SPID TTY          TIME CMD
 1054  1054 ?        00:00:00 rsyslogd
 1054  1086 ?        00:00:00 in:imuxsock
 1054  1087 ?        00:00:00 in:imklog
 1054  1090 ?        00:00:00 rs:main Q:Reg
```

(note: use either option `-C command`, or `-p PID` to select the process)

**Details threads information of a process, using custom `ps`**

```
$ ps -L -o pid,lwp,pri,nice,start,stat,bsdtime,cmd,comm  -C rsyslogd
  PID   LWP PRI  NI  STARTED STAT   TIME CMD                         COMMAND
 1054  1054  19   0 12:34:53 Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n       rsyslogd
 1054  1086  19   0 12:34:53 Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n       in:imuxsock
 1054  1087  19   0 12:34:53 Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n       in:imklog
 1054  1090  19   0 12:34:53 Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n       rs:main Q:Reg
```

Comment: What does SPID mean?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html says they're synonymous w/ lwp and tid. I suspect SPID means either Server or Session Process ID.

Answer (score 9):

You can try `top -H -p <pid>`.
But please note on some Unix flavors '-H' option is not available in `top` command.

Comment: I would venture that no UNIX supports `-H`; Linux uses GNU tools (including `ps`) and UNIX does not. (This is, of course, a generalization...)

Comment: "top -H -p <pid>" was able to do what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
ps -H le <pid>
```

This shall display threads as processes.
Also remember that all threads of a multi-threaded must have same PID. Linux does this by making thread groups. First thread is the leader of the group and its PID will be tgid(thread groupID) of the thread group.

You can find out actual PID and status of threads by using /proc file system.
Another way to achieve this is to check the PID by using ps, then run following command:

```
cat /proc/pid/status
```

Then check further pids/tgid of threads and run following command:

```
cat /proc/pid/task/threadid/status
```

Answer (score 1):

```
top -H -p <process_id>
```

This will list you the threads, associated with your process (i.e. process_id) *[Used on Ubuntu. There is possibility that the option -H is not available on some of the linux flavors]*

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same, and was able to come up with the following bash script,
This is still work in progress, I will update this as I improve the script.
I am no unix expert,I am sure some expert can write it in 2 lines, with a better quality, but my intention is to provide a working solution for others.

**update** with filter and process information

```
#!/bin/bash

ps -ef --no-headers | while read line; do                 # for each process read the info (without headers)
   IFS='        ' read -r -a array <<< "$line"             # split info into array
   psResultStr="ps -p ${array[1]} -lfT |  wc -c"           # count how many threads per PID
   numThreads=$(eval $psResultStr)                         # trying to convert it to number so i can filter later
   if [ "$numThreads" -gt "1000" ]                          #only show process with 1K or more
   then
        printf "Number of threads for PID:${array[1]} Has $numThreads Threads.  Process info: "
              for ((i = 7; i < ${#array[@]}; ++i)); do       #Process info starts at idx 7
                                position=$(( $i + 1 ))  # bash arrays are 0-indexed
                                lineText=$(echo ${array[$i]}|tr -d '\n')   # remove any new lines
                                printf "%s" "$lineText"                     #output line item
                        done
                        printf "\n\n"
   fi
done
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ps huH  -p  pid | wc  -l
```

Above command shows the number of running thread for specific process *pid* if for java process