# How does Linux tell threads apart from child processes?

Tags: linux, process, thread

Linux doesn't actually distinguish between processes and threads, and implements both as a data structure `task_struct`.

So what does Linux provide to some programs for them to tell threads of a process  from its child processes? For example, [Is there a way to see details of all the threads that a process has in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/892/is-there-a-way-to-see-details-of-all-the-threads-that-a-process-has-in-linux)

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From a `task_struct` perspective, a process’s threads have the same thread group leader ([`group_leader` in `task_struct`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/sched.h#n697)), whereas child processes have a different thread group leader (each individual child process).

This information is exposed to user space *via* the `/proc` file system. You can trace parents and children by looking at the `ppid` field in `/proc/${pid}/stat` or `.../status` (this gives the parent pid); you can trace threads by looking at the `tgid` field in `.../status` (this gives the thread group id, which is also the group leader’s pid). A process’s threads are made visible in the `/proc/${pid}/task` directory: each thread gets its own subdirectory. (Every process has at least one thread.)

In practice, programs wishing to keep track of *their own threads* would rely on APIs provided by the threading library they’re using, instead of using OS-specific information. Typically on Unix-like systems that means using pthreads.

Comment: Each process in a shell pipeline ( echo foo | cat ) shares the same group leader ( the shell ), but they are not threads in the same process.

Comment: You’re talking about process groups; in my answer, group leader is from the kernel perspective. In the kernel’s accounting, separate processes are their own group leader. You can see this by running `(sleep 120 | sleep 120) &` and looking at the  `Tgid` values in each `sleep` process’s `/proc/${pid}/status` file.

Comment: Oh weird.  I did not know there was such a thing as a "thread group leader" and I thought that supposedly all threads in a multithreaded process are equal and there is no "leader".  Any of them can exit and as long as one remains, the process isn't dead.

Answer (score 6):

1. This runs the `top` command with some extra options:

   ```
   top -H -b -n 1
   ```

   - The `-H` argument instructs top to display each individual thread.  Normally top summarizes all threads under their parent process.
   - The `-b` argument makes top run in batch mode – the information is gathered, displayed, and then dumped to stdout as opposed to running in an interactive mode and refreshing the data displayed.
   - With the `-b` option, the user must tell top how many times to run, this is done with the `-n` argument and a final argument with how many times to run.

   So `top -H -b -n 1` instructs the system to “run top, display individual threads, run in batch mode, and only run once”.
2. The `ps` command reports a snapshot of currently running processes.

   ```
   ps -eLf
   ```

   The `-eLf` argument (can be used as `-e -L -f` as well) breaks down as follows:

   - `e` tells `ps` to display all processes regardless of who owns them or their current status – active, sleeping, paused, waiting for I/O, etc.
   - `L` tells `ps` to show individual threads
   - the `f` tells `ps` to format the output as a full-format listing, and in conjunction with the `L` argument the NLWP (number of threads) and LWP (thread ID) columns are added to the output.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a process with PID p1

The `task_struct` object of a child process will have PPID (parent PID) as p1, and it's PID and TGID set to, say, p2.

The `task_struct` object of a thread of p1 will have PID set as, say p3, but TGID set to p1.

Comment: So you’re saying [the same thing as Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/434092/23408#434103), but much less clearly. P.S. Why bother bringing PPID into the discussion if you aren’t going to say what the PPID of a thread is?

Comment: PID and TGID are always the same.